# How to select a dropdownlist value using webdriver in python

Tags: python-2.7, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

The html source is below

```
<select id="ca_vdcs" class="pulldown small" name="vdc" style="display: none;">
<option>-- Select a vDC --</option>
<option>Platform-VDC-org</option>
</select>
```

I want to select the 'Platform-VDC-org', but the below code is not working.

```
select = browser.find_element_by_id('ca_vdcs')
select.find_element_by_xpath("//option[@value='Platform-VDC-org']").click()
```

Comment: Well how does it not work? Why are you not using `select.select_by_visible_text` or `select.select_by_value`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should try using the `Select()` class. It makes dealing with `select elements` much easier.

```
select = Select(browser.find_element_by_id("ca_vdcs"))
select.select_by_visible_text("Platform-VDC-org")
```

You can see the WebDriver API bindings in Python here:

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html

The `Select()` class is at section 7.12. UI Support

Comment: Was trying to find that reference in the documentation using the attached link but couldn't find it. Is that still there or am I looking at the wrong place? Thanks!

Comment: @EugeneS You're right, the docs have been reordered I guess. It's section 7.12. UI Support now. I'll update the answer.